# Django Javascript not working in HTML to Ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

I'm trying to detect changes in a Form to change the following parameters depending on the previous one.

Concretely when I change id_send_to(Client) it shows a list of companies from the client.
I think that this should be done with Ajax Call.

This is the code and when I check in the inspector I cannot see the console.log

```
{% extends "helpdesk/base.html" %}
{% load i18n bootstrap %}
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#id_send_to").change(function () {
        console.log( $(this).val() );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any Idea ?

```
<form method='post' action='./' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<fieldset>
    {{ form|bootstrap }}
        {% comment %}
        {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.is_hidden %}
            {{ field }}
        {% else %}
            <dt><label for='id_{{ field.name }}'>{% trans field.label %}</label>{% if not field.field.required %} <span class='form_optional'>{% trans "(Optional)" %}</span>{% endif %}</dt>
            <dd>{{ field }}</dd>
            {% if field.errors %}<dd class='error'>{{ field.errors }}</dd>{% endif %}
            {% if field.help_text %}<dd class='form_help_text'>{% trans field.help_text %}</dd>{% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endcomment %}

<div class='buttons form-group'>
    <input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" value='{% trans "Submit 
Ticket" %}' />
</div>
</fieldset>

{% csrf_token %}</form>
```

Comment: try .on('change', function () {}

Comment: Tried but didn't work...